# how to collect json with same value in one view and others in another view and make a dynamic view

Tags: android, json, listview, view

i have json as bellow :

```
 {  
"transaksi": {
        "jenis_link": "unit_link",
        "rks_ulink": [
            {
                "lji_invest": "Excellink Dynamic Fund",
                "tgl": "22/05/2013",
                "harga_unit": "3,581.38",
                "nilai": "0.000",
                "total_unit": "0.0000"
            },
            {
                "lji_invest": "Excellink Aggressive Fund",
                "tgl": "22/05/2013",
                "harga_unit": "3,758.73",
                "nilai": "35,737,078.757",
                "total_unit": "9,507.7435"
            }
        ],
"ulink": [
            {
                "jumlah_unit": 46.9545,
                "investasi": "Excellink Aggressive Fund",
                "harga_unit": 2041.807,
                "tgl_nab": "25/07/2007",
                "transaksi": "Alokasi Investasi",
                "jumlah": 95872
            },
            {
                "jumlah_unit": 54.722,
                "investasi": "Excellink Aggressive Fund",
                "harga_unit": 1827.417,
                "tgl_nab": "27/08/2007",
                "transaksi": "Alokasi Investasi",
                "jumlah": 100000
            },
            {
                "jumlah_unit": -2.2826,
                "investasi": "Excellink Aggressive Fund",
                "harga_unit": 1857.119,
                "tgl_nab": "17/09/2007",
                "transaksi": "Penarikan-Potongan Aug 07",
                "jumlah": 4239
            },

            {
                "jumlah_unit": 186.3333,
                "investasi": "Excellink Dynamic Fund",
                "harga_unit": 2146.691,
                "tgl_nab": "25/10/2007",
                "transaksi": "Alokasi Investasi",
                "jumlah": 400000
            },
            {
                "jumlah_unit": -7.5143,
                "investasi": "Excellink Dynamic Fund",
                "harga_unit": 2185.977,
                "tgl_nab": "01/11/2007",
                "transaksi": "Penarikan-Potongan Oct 07",
                "jumlah": 16426
            },
            {
                "jumlah_unit": 186.2001,
                "investasi": "Excellink Dynamic Fund",
                "harga_unit": 2148.226,
                "tgl_nab": "26/11/2007",
                "transaksi": "Alokasi Investasi",
                "jumlah": 400000
            },
            {
                "jumlah_unit": -7.5314,
                "investasi": "Excellink Dynamic Fund",
                "harga_unit": 2183.127,
                "tgl_nab": "03/12/2007",
                "transaksi": "Penarikan-Potongan Nov 07",
                "jumlah": 16442
            },
            {
                "jumlah_unit": 183.0457,
                "investasi": "Excellink Dynamic Fund",
                "harga_unit": 2185.247,
                "tgl_nab": "26/12/2007",
                "transaksi": "Alokasi Investasi",
                "jumlah": 400000
            }        ]
    }
}
```

as you see, few json `"investasi"` values are same with `"Excellink Dynamic Fund"` and others with `"Excellink Aggressive Fund"` . i want to collect it base one json json `"investasi"`with same values, but my problems are i don't know how to collect it in one view and others in others view. for detail i enclosure two image :

json `"investasi"` values are same with `"Excellink Dynamic Fund"`

[image]

under this view is json `"investasi"` values are same with `"Excellink Aggressive Fund"`

[image]

so far i have make two layout, first layout is containing listview :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@color/medium_gray">
     <TextView 
                android:id="@+id/title"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:textColor="#FF0000"
                android:text="TRANSAKSI"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:divider="#000000"
                 android:dividerHeight="1dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="8dp"/>

   <TableRow
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

       <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            style="@style/size10ptWhite3dpBold"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight=".35"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:paddingTop="5dip"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip">

        <!--Kolom 1-->
        <TextView
            android:text="Transaksi"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip" />

    </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Kolom 2 -->
        <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                style="@style/size10ptWhite3dpBold"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_weight=".35"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="5dip"
                android:paddingBottom="10dip" >

        <TextView
            android:text="Jumlah"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:text="Tanggal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#b5b5b5"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"/>
    </LinearLayout> 

        <!-- Kolom 3 -->
    <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                style="@style/size10ptWhite3dpBold"              
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_weight=".30"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="5dip"
                android:paddingBottom="10dip">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jumlah_unit"
            android:text="Jumlah Unit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip" 
            android:gravity="right"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/harga_unit"
            android:text="Harga Unit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="#b5b5b5"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"/>

    </LinearLayout>

        </TableRow>
        <LinearLayout 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                <include layout="@layout/line"/>
            </LinearLayout>

       <ListView
        android:id="@android:id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="#000000"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="false"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

second layout for value json :

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:background="@color/medium_gray">

    <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            style="@style/size10ptWhite3dpBold"
            android:layout_width="0dip"
            android:layout_weight=".33"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:paddingTop="5dip"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip">

        <!--Kolom 1-->
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/transaksi"
            android:text="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="17sp"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip" />

    </LinearLayout>

        <!-- Kolom 2 -->
        <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                style="@style/size10ptWhite3dpBold"
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_weight=".33"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="5dip"
                android:paddingBottom="10dip" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jumlah"
            android:text="Jumlah"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"
            android:gravity="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tanggal"
            android:text="Tanggal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#b5b5b5"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"/>
    </LinearLayout> 

        <!-- Kolom 3 -->
    <LinearLayout
                xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                style="@style/size10ptWhite3dpBold"              
                android:layout_width="0dip"
                android:layout_weight=".33"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:paddingTop="5dip"
                android:paddingBottom="10dip">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/jumlah_unit"
            android:text="Jumlah Unit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:paddingTop="10dip"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip" 
            android:gravity="right"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/harga_unit"
            android:text="Harga_Unit"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="#b5b5b5"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:paddingBottom="10dip"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

this is how i parse my json :

```
      JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

                            JSONObject transaksi = jsonObject.getJSONObject("transaksi");
                            for (int i=0; i<transaksi.length();i++){
                            String jenis_link = transaksi.getString("jenis_link");

RingkasanUlinkVariabel VarRKS = null;
                            JSONArray rks_ulink = transaksi.getJSONArray("rks_ulink");
                            for (int j=0; j<rks_ulink.length();j++){
                                JSONObject rks = rks_ulink.getJSONObject(j);
                                VarRKS= new RingkasanUlinkVariabel(rks.optString("lji_invest"),
                                        rks.optString("total_unit"),
                                        rks.optString("harga_unit"),
                                        rks.optString("nilai"),
                                        rks.optString("tgl"));
                                ListRingkasan.add(VarRKS);
                                System.out.println("Adam levine");

                            }
                                UnitLinkVariabel VarUnit = null;
                            JSONArray ulink = transaksi.getJSONArray("ulink");
                            for (int k=0; k<ulink.length();k++){
                            JSONObject unit = ulink.getJSONObject(k);
                            VarUnit= new UnitLinkVariabel(unit.optString("investasi"),
                                    unit.optString("transaksi"),
                                    unit.optString("jumlah"),
                                    unit.optString("tgl_nab"),
                                    unit.optString("jumlah_unit"),
                                    unit.optString("harga_unit"));
                            ListUnitLink.add(VarUnit);
```

so how to collect json with same value in one view and others in another view and make a dynamic view in one layout? i hope somebody can help me to solve my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one :

```
//Declare a different list for containing the UnitLinkVariabel
//one for the "Aggressive" and one for the "Dynamic"
List ListUnitLinkEAF = new ArrayList<UnitLinkVariabel>();
List ListUnitLinkEDF = new ArrayList<UnitLinkVariabel>();

//Declare the handler for each UnitLinkVariabel, 
//again, one for Aggressive, one for Dynamic
UnitLinkVariabel VarUnitEAF = null;
UnitLinkVariabel VarUnitEDF = null;
```

Under the :

```
   for (int k=0; k<ulink.length();k++){
         JSONObject unit = ulink.getJSONObject(k);
```

add a check like this :

```
         if (unit.optString("investasi").equals("Excellink Aggressive Fund") {
             VarUnitEAF = new UnitLinkVariabel(unit.optString("transaksi"),
                          unit.optString("jumlah"),
                          unit.optString("tgl"),
                          unit.optString("jumlah_unit"),
                          unit.optString("harga_unit"));
             ListUnitLinkEAF.add(VarUnitEAF);
         } else if (unit.optString("investasi").equals("Excellink Dynamic Fund") {
             VarUnitEDF = new UnitLinkVariabel(unit.optString("transaksi"),
                          unit.optString("jumlah"),
                          unit.optString("tgl"),
                          unit.optString("jumlah_unit"),
                          unit.optString("harga_unit"));
             ListUnitLinkEDF.add(VarUnitEDF);
         }
```

Now you have 2 list, one with `Excellink Aggressive Fund or (EAF)`, and one with `Excellink Dynamic Fund or (EDF)`

What you need to do now is put each list into the ListView, if you want both of them to be displayed, prepare 2 listviews, one for EAF and one for EDF. I'll leave you with inserting the data into the listView.

Good Luck :)

**EDIT**

use `Set<String>` to get the values of `Investasi`, read all the entries of `UnitLinkVariabel`, and put all the string within `Investasi` inside the `Set`.

As you know, a `Set` cannot have duplicates, so this is what you're looking for.

Here's some snippet :

```
//Declare the set
Set<String> investasi = new LinkedHashSet<String>();
```

now, read all the `Investasi` and add it into `investasi`

```
   for (int k=0; k<ulink.length();k++){
         JSONObject unit = ulink.getJSONObject(k);
         investasi.add(unit.optString("investasi"));
    }
```

Then, for each `investasi`, do something :

```
for (String jenisInvestasi : investasi) {
     for (int k=0; k<ulink.length();k++){
         JSONObject unit = ulink.getJSONObject(k);
         if (unit.optString("investasi").equals(jenisInvestasi)) {
            //insert into list
         }
}
```

There's the logic, you should be able to find the rest of the code yourself, good luck :D

Comment: well this is so close to what i need, but value from "investasi" not just "Excellink Aggressive Fund" and "Excellink dynamic Fund" because value from "investasi" is unlimited. so how to solve problem like this? and how can i prepare listview  with this condition? thank you

Comment: what do you mean by unlimited? the code above will check every UnitLink before inserting it into the list. If the `unitLink` is EAF, insert it into `ListUnitLinkEAF`, how do you use the listview in the first place?

Comment: i mean value that i got from "investasi" is possible not just "Excellink Aggressive Fund" and "Excellink dynamic Fund", is possible other values such us "dollar fund", "rupiah fund" or etc,  because product from "investasi" is so much, that's why i want to make it dynamic, not static

Comment: Then you will need to check all the values first, inserting them into an array for a check. If the value of `unitLink.optString("investasi")` is not available inside array, then add it into the array, and then add the respective data. if it is available, just insert the data without adding the string into the array. This is a very complex operation...

Comment: yup.. this is very complex operation.. well.. first i'll try your suggest and made some update if i have some error

Answer (score 0):

for handle it i have made some logic as bellow :

1. add two new array list they are :

private ArrayList StringUnit []; // for handle array list that i've split
private ArrayList kelompok; // for handle array list

```
this is how i parse my json :



 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(result);

                                JSONObject transaksi = jsonObject.getJSONObject("transaksi");
                                for (int i=0; i<transaksi.length();i++){
                                String jenis_link = transaksi.getString("jenis_link");

    RingkasanUlinkVariabel VarRKS = null;
                                JSONArray rks_ulink = transaksi.getJSONArray("rks_ulink");
                                for (int j=0; j<rks_ulink.length();j++){
                                    JSONObject rks = rks_ulink.getJSONObject(j);
                                    VarRKS= new RingkasanUlinkVariabel(rks.optString("lji_invest"),
                                            rks.optString("total_unit"),
                                            rks.optString("harga_unit"),
                                            rks.optString("nilai"),
                                            rks.optString("tgl"));
                                    ListRingkasan.add(VarRKS);
                                    System.out.println("Adam levine");

                                }
                                    UnitLinkVariabel VarUnit = null;
                                    JSONArray ulink = transaksi.getJSONArray("ulink");
                                    for (int k=0; k<ulink.length();k++){
                                    JSONObject unit = ulink.getJSONObject(k);
                                    VarUnit= new UnitLinkVariabel(unit.optString("investasi"),unit.optString("transaksi"),
                                            unit.optString("jumlah"),
                                            unit.optString("tgl"),
                                            unit.optString("jumlah_unit"),
                                            unit.optString("harga_unit"));
                                    ListUnitLink.add(VarUnit);

                                    // this is how i divide my arraylist and collect them 

                                    String[] mStringArray = new String[ListUnitLink.size()];
                                    mStringArray = ListUnitLink.toArray(mStringArray);

                                    for(int e= 0; e < mStringArray.length ; e++){
                                        kelompok.add(mStringArray[e]);
                                        if (mStringArray.optString("investasi") == mStringArray[e-1].optString("investasi"))
                                        {
                                            StringUnit.add(kelompok);
                                        }
```

well this is not finish because i have stack at here. i don't know wether my logic is wrong or false.

Comment: I already had an idea about how to do it, I will post it later :)